# How to change numeration in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering, chapters

I've got a problem while trying to figure out a structure for `report` document.

At this moment I have:

```
\chapter[Chapter 1]{}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section{Section 2}
```

Effect of that in ToC is:

```
1. Chapter 1
1.1 Section 1
1.1.1 Subsection 1
1.1.2 Subsection 2
1.2 Section 2
```

What I'm looking for is:

```
Chapter 1
1 Section 1
1.1 Subsection 1
1.2 Subsection 2
2 Section 2
```

I already tried using `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1}`, but obviously it solved problem only with chapter and wrong numeration for sections and subsections is still happening.
I've tested changing `\chapter` to `\part` as well. Unfortunately effect is not satisfying since it causes even more problems to fix in ToC and document structure.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Do you want to have this numeration in ToC only or in the body as well?

Comment: Thanks. Numeration in the body must be the same as numeration in ToC.

Comment: See my answer below please then-- I think this is what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This removes the `\thechapter` counter output from the `\thesection` counter formatting. Since `\thesubsection` etc. are recursively using `\thesection` etc. this will provide the correct numbering for all sectioning commands.

Please note that this will change the numbering within the body as well!

Most likely, the spacing should be changed!

```
\documentclass{book}


\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter[Chapter 1]{}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section{Section 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Mixed with \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{}, done it's job perfectly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

If you want normal numbering in the body, you can use the `\p@section` feature.

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\p@section}{\thechapter.}
\renewcommand{\p@subsection}{\thechapter.}
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname\quad
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}\label{ch1}
\section{Section 1}\label{sec1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}\label{ssec1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section{Section 2}

\ref{ch1}; \ref{sec1}; \ref{ssec1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also want to remove the number next to the chapter title in the TOC, you can either patch `\@makechapterhead` or `\l@chapter`.

The latter method consists in adding

```
\let\original@l@chapter\l@chapter
\renewcommand{\l@chapter}[2]{%
  \begingroup\let\numberline\@gobble\original@l@chapter{#1}{#2}\endgroup
}
```

just before `\makeatother` in the code above.

The other method requires `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\p@section}{\thechapter.}
\renewcommand{\p@subsection}{\thechapter.}
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname\quad
}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\numberline}{\@gobble}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}\label{ch1}
\section{Section 1}\label{sec1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}\label{ssec1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section{Section 2}

\ref{ch1}; \ref{sec1}; \ref{ssec1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also get the same with `tocloft`.

Comment: @Mico That's a job for `tocloft`, of course.

Comment: @Mico I added a couple of ways